# How does a goroutine behave when it creates a channel

Tags: go

Suppose I have a function which creates a goroutine and inside that goroutine, I create a channel. My question is that when we create N go routines, N separate channels will be created?

A sample code here:

```
func createAChannel() {

  // make a channel

}
func main() {
  for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
  go createAChannel()}

}
```

Comment: This question is liable to downvoting since you haven't provided any relevant code.

Comment: I added some sample code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, every time you create a channel with `make`, you get a new channel.

If you want multiple goroutines to share a channel instead, you have to create the channel in the parent goroutine and pass it to the child goroutines.